# use python importlib causes lost autocomplete and lint

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, pylint, python-importlib

First. Some context. I have a class that helps to import several modules, as this will be done dynamically it is important to use the importlib library, so far everything works fine. BUT ... autocomplete capability is completely lost and the lint is not responding (vs-code).

The question is: How do I recover the autocomplete and the lint?

Here is the example code:

```
# ----------- file foo.py
import typing, types, importlib

print("foo was imported!")

class foo () : 
    def __init__ ( self ) : pass
    def foo_get_doble( self, number : int ) -> int : return number*2
    def foo_print_hello_word( self ) -> None : print("hello world")


# ----------- file __init__.py
import typing, sys, importlib

if __package__ : 
    template_module = importlib.import_module( f"{__package__}.foo" )
else : 
    print( "NO PKG" )
    sys.path.append( r"C:\working_folder" )
    foo_mod = importlib.import_module( "foo" )

importlib.reload( foo_mod )
# foo_class = foo_mod.  # NO HINTS NO LINT NO TYPE CHECK NOTHING (vs-code)
foo_class = foo_mod.foo() # but its there. works.

#output
# NO PKG
# foo was imported!
# foo was imported!
```

What I expect after the import :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUU5R.png)

What I get :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fexft.png)

**EDIT**

after a long search. It seems that importlib does not return the custom module as such. But a TypeModule or something. Which is a kind of generic module class. When I get anything from the module, I get such a TypeAny. However, knowing this does not solve the problem. How I cast the type. or as a fill in the module so that the classes and methods are recognized?

Comment: Do you mean that before importing the module "importlib", when you enter "foo_class = foo_mod.", is VSCode's automatic completion available? Have you checked whether the python code analysis tool [Pylint](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting) is available in the python environment you are currently using?

Comment: I update the question, I hope it's clearer

Comment: -How are things going? Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful.

Comment: I write a answer too. You was getting autocompled because the line:   from de.foo import fo    is a static typed  (not use importlib) . you put de.foo because you know the variable before hand. This is why I use importlib. The import is user-defined.  Thansk Jill, read your anwser indirectly help to discovery was happen.

Comment: -You can mark your reply as an answer to help others who have the same doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research. **It's impossible**. Because the data is created in runtime. So... VSCode (or any editor) can get the information before hand. Is only possible after the creation, after the execution. The more near solution is use a Jupyter Notebook, but is no suitable for larges files.

Comment: Isnt there a switch to add `import mymodule` in case the analyser runs, which will find the module... ??

Answer (score 1):

In VS Code, Python's Linting function and auto-completion function are provided by the Python extension. Therefore, it is recommended that you reinstall the python extension and reload VS Code.

For the use of the python code analysis tool, take Pylint as an example, please install the module "pylint" in the python environment you are currently using, and then run it.

[image]

Update:

When I use "`from de.foo import fo`" to import the method fo() in the file "`foo.py`", "`class_foo.f`" shows the auto-completion option:

[image]

Since VS Code starts from the parent folder of the current file by default when searching for files, as an example to ensure the code runs, I added the code

```
import sys
sys.path.append("./")
```

, which adds the file path to the system path to help VS Code find it.

Reference: [Linting in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting).

Comment: Hmm, you're half right. but it is that you cannot get the 3 methods of foo_class. What it shows now are methods and attributes of a ... generic class? it's supposed to show: foo_class.f -> foo_get_doble () and foo_print_hello_world ().
I'll update the question by adding this.

Comment: @user70587 -I updated my answer, and you could refer to it.